# Difference between Lord Rama and Lord Vishnu bows

Tags: vishnu, ramayana, rama

Kodanda and Sharanga are bows of Lord Rama and Lord Vishnu respectively. Are both of them same or different? If different ,in what aspect they differ?

Comment: great question! my guess is they're the same bow but different names. Since Rama = Vishnu, he just takes different names during avatara, his weapons also take different names during avatara. Parashurama had Vishnu-dhanush with him, which Rama took during their meeting.