# Are Kodanda and Sharanga bows same and how did Lord Rama get it?

Tags: ramayana, rama

Kodanda is the bow of Rama ( not sure if it has any other names). Is it same as Sharanga of Vishnu? How has Rama come in possession of Kodanda?

Comment: Wikipedia says they are the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/difference-between-lord-rama-and-lord-vishnu-bows

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury yeah.. partly.. how Lord Rama came in possession of the bow is part of the question too.. I will edit the title to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Kodanda is the bow gifted to Rama by the sage Agasthya when he visited him in the dandakaranya. I think saranga is the bow given by Parashurama in their encounter after Sita svayamvar.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).